# What is an UIImageView and how do I rotate it

Tags: iphone, xcode

From what I understand an UIImageView can contain a UIImage.  Using the UIImageView you can then rotate the UIImage.
This, I believe, is done by assigning the UIImage an image of some sort and then, somehow, assigning the UIImage to the UIImageView.

I believe that I have "set" an image directly to a UIImageView and now wish to spin this image pinwheel style.

Is this possible or do I need to re-write so that my image is associated with an UIImage which is then, in turn, associated with the UIImageView?

I currently am using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to attempt this on the UIImageView and the rotation looks more like it is flipping end over end and round and round.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, a `UIImageView` is just a view that knows how do draw an image on screen.  That is it.

If you want to animate the spinning of an image you can either:

1. create separate images and load the array of images into the `UIImageView`; or
2. load a single image and use Core Animation to rotate the image.

Applying just a transform on the view will change it but won't animate it.  That is what Core Animation is for.

Comment: Figured out the issue...  I was putting the animation code in a timer that was running 60 times a second.  Thus, I believe, the animation was "beginning" 60 times a second... kept resetting.